# How do I move a search-filtered set of emails out of Inbox?

Tags: gmail

I want to clean up my Gmail.
There's a bunch of emails having desired specific label and undesire Inbox label. I know I can move it one by one, but that's too stupid and time consuming.
How do I move them out of Inbox, search-based, not individually?

Answer (score 5):

Assuming that you have all the conversations as a result of a search such as "in:inbox label:labelx"

Select all the conversations by clicking in the box just above where the stars are. This is also a pull down so you can pick from some other options. If there are more results than can fit on the page, a clickable link will appear at the top of the results: "All 100 conversations on this page are selected. Select all conversations that match this search". Click it it you want to work with more than a page at a time.

At this point you will also have a new button at the top of the page. The "Archive" button does one thing. It removes the "inbox" label. Click the button and those conversations will no longer be displayed on the front page.